# how can i use regex to remove the following? (nothing is working so far)

Tags: python, regex, pandas

i have all my column values with:

```
[7211.0]
[45]
[34]
```

and my object columns as:

```
['harry']
['sally']
```

i have tried eveyrthing to remove these e.g.:

```
df['name']=df['name'].str.strip("[]'")
df['name'] = df['name'].replace(r'\[.*?\]','',regex=True)
```

but this leaves my columns with all nan! what else can i do?

Comment: Try `df['name'].str[0]`

Comment: `[ ]` is not part of data but information that you have list with item(s) - and it means you have to get element(s) from list - you can't treat it as string with chars `[ ]`

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is not part of data but information that you have list with item(s).
You can't treat it as string with chars `[]`.

You have to get item from list and assign to other (or the same column)

For single value from list you can use `.str[index]`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'name': [
        ['harry','x'],
        ['sally','y']
    ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df['name'] = df['name'].str[0]
print(df)
```

Before

```
         name
0  [harry, x]
1  [sally, y]
```

After

```
    name
0  harry
1  sally
```

---

To extract all values to separated columns you many need `apply(pd.Series)`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'name': [
        ['harry', 'x'],
        ['sally', 'y']
    ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df[['name', 'char']] = df['name'].apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
```

Before

```
         name
0  [harry, x]
1  [sally, y]
```

After

```
    name char
0  harry    x
1  sally    y
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your DataFrame looks something like this:

```py
>>> df
    name  num
0  harry  600.90
1  sally  300.03
>>> df.dtypes
name    object
num      float64
dtype: object
```

The enclosing square brackets are not actually part of the data you are looking to match and replace with regex i.e The column for Harry contains the string `harry` not `[harry]`.

Changing your existing regex pattern to reflect this will result in the functionality you are seeking to implement.

```py
df['name'] = df['name'].replace(r'.*','',regex=True)
```

Updated DataFrame:

```py
>>> df
  name     num
0       600.90
1       300.03
>>> df.dtypes
name     object
num     float64
dtype: object
```